# Exit on backbutton pressed

Tags: android, android-activity, back-button

I have two activities.

1. MainActivity
2. ListActivity

After some job in  MainActivity, ListAllActivity starts. 
I want to exit the application when back button pressed from ListAllActivity. And my code for this is,

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(intent);
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

**But, when I'm pressing the back Button from ListAllActivity , it simply brings me back to MainActivity.**

The AndroidManifest entry for these Activities are :

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.myapps.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/loading" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.myapps.ListAllActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_list_all" >

    </activity>
```

Please help.

Comment: u can write finish Also..

Comment: After Starting `Intent` from first `Activity` to another use `this.finish()` for end of `Activity`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the below steps

- From the `MainActivity` you need to call the `finish()` method after you pass intent to `ListAllActivity`
- In the `ListAllActivity` call the finish() method on your button click or just press the back button as back button by default call `finish()` method.
- In this way you will exit from your app.

On the next button click of `MainActivity` write below code

```
Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,ListAllActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

and on the `ListAllActivity` back button write below code

```
finish();
```

Answer (score 1):

When you fire intent from MainActivity to ListActivity then call `finish();` like

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ListActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to finish your `MainActivity` before your start your `ListAllActivity` and finish your `ListAllActivity` on `onBackpressed`  as below:

Supposing you are starting your `ListAllActivity` from mainactivity.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

     ....................
      //Supposing you are starting activity on button click write as below in your onclick event. 
     Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ListActivity.class);
      startActivity(intent);
    finish();

  }
}
```

In your `ListAllActivity`

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    finish();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ListActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

Pass intent like this to start the list activity from first activity and while u press back in the list activity app will exit.

Answer (score 0):

This is all you need here

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed ()
{       
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use my snippet in onBackPressed() to kill the process using process id. Its simple and much more efficient.

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to call `finish()` method:

```
Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,ListAllActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Also on the ListAllActivity back button write below code:

```
finish();
```